# Как переопределить ошибку потери связи?

Tags: android, vkontakte-api

При запуске приложения (при отсутствии интернета) пишет ошибку:

net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

Тут же появляется возможность повторить или закрыть окно. Как переопределить эту ошибку? Скажем, чтобы писало текст: "Подключение к интернету отсутствует. Повторите подключение позже".

Если это поможет, то уточню: ошибка появляется при запуске метода VKSdk.login()  из библиотеки VK.com для android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё зависит от ваших дальнейших действий если нет подключения. 
Отлавливать ошибки это конечно хорошо, но здесь явный пример когда вы должны учитывать состояние сети, и в одном из них не тревожить ваш метод. Пример из [оф дока](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html?hl=ru#DetermineType):

```
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
if (isConnected) VKSdk.login();
else System.out.println("Подключение к интернету отсутствует. Повторите подключение позже");
```